# Where is the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler.dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use the profiler in visual studio to find the bottleneck in my application. I want to test 1 method in particular so, I was following this guide :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514149.aspx

But I got stuck on this part...

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler;
```

According to the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.profiler.datacollection.aspx), this namespace is part of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler.dll, but I can't find this dll when I tried to add a reference to my project.

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you actually added Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler.dll as a reference to your project. You'll need to do that otherwise your `using` statement will throw an exception.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I'm trying to add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler.dll as a reference to my project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Your build must reference the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler.dll
>   library, located in the Microsoft Visual Studio 9\Team
>   Tools\Performance Tools directory.

This is from [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514149.aspx). Obviously if you have version higher than 9 you will look into that version.

Comment: For VS 2012, look here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools

Comment: For VS 2017: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\x64\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler.dll

Comment: Anyone know if this is still available in VS 2019 or 2022? I haven't been able to find it in similar locations.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't have to be "9" in the path. probably whichever version you're having. for you (2013) it'll be here:

[image]

not sure what the others are.

[link in higher res here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdVzz.png).

Having said that, have a look at the above windows utility: [everything search](http://www.voidtools.com/). you can type the name of the dll you're looking for, and results are instantaneous :)